# SSRS - Toggling visibility of report items based on the visibility state of other report items

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm trying to make a report in SSRS, and I'd like to toggle the visibility of sections of the report if one section of the report is visible or not.

If section1 is visible
    then section2, section3, section4 are hidden;
If section2 is visible
    then section1, section3, section4 are hidden;
If section3 is visible
    then section1, section2, section4 are hidden;
If section4 is visible
    then section1, section2, section3 are hidden;

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to define which one is visable using a variable or hidden parameter?

I'd set a parameter with four options 1, 2, 3 and 4, then depending on which one is selected set the visability of the other section individually. E.g. if you used an expression in the visability property of section 1 to `=iif(Paramater!Section_Visable.Value=1, false, true)`

Comment: I realise now that I didn't quite describe what I was doing fully. Sorry!  The user is setting which sections are showing by clicking through items in each of the sections, so each section behaves pretty much like a different page.  I originally had this set up as a number of different reports, but the problem with that is that the queries run each time you click between reports, which is s l o w...

Comment: So if I were to use a parameter to do this, is there then some way of setting the parameter based on clicking on items in the report?  I'd prefer not to use a drop-down or something in the parameter bar, as I think that would be a lot less intuitive for the users.

Comment: @user1945205, thanks for your interestin my answer. I would the use [variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3fb712(v=vs.80).aspx) and possibly a user function to set this. You could use a function in the clickable items that returns nothing in the expression but updates the variable?